# React and vite problem , i not use tailwind but problem postcss

Tags: reactjs, vite

I inizialize the project run with npm run dev and result is:

```
17:49:16 [vite] Internal server error: [postcss] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')
```

Running and running react vite and javascript without typescript or other